# Tool for moving API code from monolith to micro-service

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, sails.js, code-migration

We are currently in the process of moving code from our monoliths to different micro-services. There are 2 monoliths one using express, the other using sails on top of nodejs. I have already moved a few APIs at this point to one of the services. However I notice that it takes a lot of time copying code from the monolith to the micro-service manually for each API. Note that we are not using classes in the monolith, its all individual methods.

I feel there might be tools for moving relevant code from one repo to another. I am assuming say I input the repository and the starting function for an API the tool should be able to detect all functions required for executing any call made to the API and should be able to move them to the micro-service. If there are no such tools what can I use to build one for my use case, or am I oversimplifying the problem and am better off copy pasting code from one repo to another and then refactoring it.

Comment: Consider moving to a monorepo instead ([ref](https://monorepo.tools). This will give you the freedom to easily refactor across (micro-)services, without the cumbersome copying of code between repos, and the monorepo tools such as NX will give you the visibility into the dependencies.

Comment: We have already shifted to a micro-service, in this case, so would not be able to explore this option. Is this similar to what Shopify is doing with modular monoliths.

Comment: Yes, it's similar. For our project, we want to move from ~10 micro-services to hosting all of them in a single monorepo, using nx to manage interdependencies. I believe we won't need much code changes for it - just moving the code, maybe adjust import paths, and change a lot of devops stuff